# Get products that are in stock

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce2, ecommerce

In Craft Commerce 2, how can I query products that are in stock? These are products without variants.

#### Edit: Perhaps this is a Craft-bug?

This particular product type used to support variants - but I removed that support prior to importing all the products with Feed Me.

When I look at the `commerce_producttypes`-table, I see some remnants of data in the `variantFieldLayoutId` suggesting that the product type supports variants:

[image: variantFieldLayoutId seems to suggest that product type still supports variants]

When I run queries such as:

`{% set children = craft.products.hasVariant({ hasStock: true }).limit(50) %}`

I actually only get products from the three other product types (that has never supported variants).

But when I run queries such as:

`{% set children = craft.products({ type: 'threads' }).productImage(":notempty:").limit(20) %}`

I do get products from the product type "threads". Strange eh?

I tried setting the `variantFieldLayoutId` field to `Null`, but it didn't yield any difference.

I tried deleting the product type, re-adding it and re-importing all the products, but still same result.

#### Something weird with variants

When I run the following query:

`craft.products({ type: 'threads' }).productImage(":notempty:").hasVariant({ hasStock: true }).limit(20)`

I get no results. It produces the following query:

```sql
SELECT -- loads of fields
FROM (SELECT `elements`.`id` AS `elementsId`, `elements_sites`.`id` AS `elementsSitesId`, `content`.`id` AS `contentId`
FROM `elements` `elements`
INNER JOIN `commerce_products` `commerce_products` ON `commerce_products`.`id` = `elements`.`id`
INNER JOIN `elements_sites` `elements_sites` ON `elements_sites`.`elementId` = `elements`.`id`
INNER JOIN `content` `content` ON (`content`.`elementId` = `elements`.`id`) AND (`content`.`siteId` = `elements_sites`.`siteId`)
WHERE (`commerce_products`.`typeId`='6') AND (`commerce_products`.`id` IN ('16458', '16477', '16491')) AND (`elements_sites`.`siteId`='1') AND ((select count(`relations_productImage`.`id`) from `relations` `relations_productImage` where `relations_productImage`.`sourceId` = `elements`.`id` and `relations_productImage`.`fieldId` = '94') != 0) AND (`elements`.`archived`=FALSE) AND (((`elements`.`enabled`=TRUE) AND (`elements_sites`.`enabled`=TRUE)) AND (`commerce_products`.`postDate` <= '2019-12-02 10:31:14') AND ((`commerce_products`.`expiryDate` IS NULL) OR (`commerce_products`.`expiryDate` > '2019-12-02 10:31:14'))) AND (`elements`.`dateDeleted` IS NULL) AND (`elements_sites`.`enabled`=TRUE) AND (`elements`.`draftId` IS NULL) AND (`elements`.`revisionId` IS NULL)
ORDER BY `commerce_products`.`postDate` DESC
LIMIT 20) `subquery`
INNER JOIN `commerce_products` `commerce_products` ON `commerce_products`.`id` = `subquery`.`elementsId`
INNER JOIN `elements` `elements` ON `elements`.`id` = `subquery`.`elementsId`
INNER JOIN `elements_sites` `elements_sites` ON `elements_sites`.`id` = `subquery`.`elementsSitesId`
INNER JOIN `content` `content` ON `content`.`id` = `subquery`.`contentId`
ORDER BY `commerce_products`.`postDate` DESC
```

Notice the `AND ('commerce_products'.'id' IN ('16458', '16477', '16491'))`

When I remove it, I get the results I expect. The three IDs belong to the only three products that are not part of the product type 6 (former type 5 in the screenshot).

#### More hasVariant subquery weirdness

When I run this query:

```
{% set children = craft.products({
    type: 'threads'
}).hasVariant({
    stock: '> 1',
}) %}
```

Which creates this SQL:

```sql
SELECT 

-- loads of fields

FROM (SELECT `elements`.`id` AS `elementsId`, `elements_sites`.`id` AS `elementsSitesId`, `content`.`id` AS `contentId`
FROM `elements` `elements`
INNER JOIN `commerce_products` `commerce_products` ON `commerce_products`.`id` = `elements`.`id`
INNER JOIN `elements_sites` `elements_sites` ON `elements_sites`.`elementId` = `elements`.`id`
INNER JOIN `content` `content` ON (`content`.`elementId` = `elements`.`id`) AND (`content`.`siteId` = `elements_sites`.`siteId`)
WHERE (`commerce_products`.`typeId`='6') AND (`commerce_products`.`id` IN 
('20396', '20447', '20495', 

-- plus all other ids that belong to products with variants that have a stock greater than 0

)) AND (`elements_sites`.`siteId`='1') AND (`elements`.`archived`=FALSE) AND (((`elements`.`enabled`=TRUE) AND (`elements_sites`.`enabled`=TRUE)) AND (`commerce_products`.`postDate` <= '2019-12-02 11:02:06') AND ((`commerce_products`.`expiryDate` IS NULL) OR (`commerce_products`.`expiryDate` > '2019-12-02 11:02:06'))) AND (`elements`.`dateDeleted` IS NULL) AND (`elements_sites`.`enabled`=TRUE) AND (`elements`.`draftId` IS NULL) AND (`elements`.`revisionId` IS NULL)
ORDER BY `commerce_products`.`postDate` DESC) `subquery`
INNER JOIN `commerce_products` `commerce_products` ON `commerce_products`.`id` = `subquery`.`elementsId`
INNER JOIN `elements` `elements` ON `elements`.`id` = `subquery`.`elementsId`
INNER JOIN `elements_sites` `elements_sites` ON `elements_sites`.`id` = `subquery`.`elementsSitesId`
INNER JOIN `content` `content` ON `content`.`id` = `subquery`.`contentId`
ORDER BY `commerce_products`.`postDate` DESC
```

I actually get the desired result: All products (variants) that have stock > 0.

Answer (score 1):

Even without *Products of this type have multiple variants* enabled on your product type, a product still has one variant so doing the below should work.

```
{% set products = craft.variants().hasStock().all() %}
```

Comment: See updated question.